# Red check mark automatically removed after a second after changing a file in Visual Studio

Tags: git, version-control, visual-studio-2013, git-extensions, assembla

I use Visual Studio with GIT/Assembla and in most projects when I change a file there is a red check mark before the file in the Solution Explorer, meaning it can be commited later via GIT/Assembla.

However, in one project, there are files and after saving changes from a file in that project, a red check flag is shown, but is automatically removed after a few seconds. 
Also when I try to commit the changes to the local/remote repository, that changed file is not in the list (thus it will never be part of the remote repository).

I removed (manually) a .git folder inside the project where the files are are, so it looks like a sort of git-sub project inside the solution.

Does anybody know how to fix this problem?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

The .git folder is your local git repository - this folder contains information about the remote as well as the history, tags, branches and other information for your git repository. Removing this is probably what caused your issues.

I would create a new project, clone the git repo from Assembla again, then copy your changes over from your old project.

Comment: I deleted and created a new Assembla repo but now everything seems to work again. I lost my history but that is not a big deal for now.